# How to check enum and model property inside kendo template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-template, kendo-listview

I am trying to write below template but after execution,i am getting Invalid Template Error in console.

```
    @using MYApplication.EnumContract
    @model MYApplication.Models.CustomerModel
    <script type="text/kendo-x-tmpl" id="EntitiesTemplate">
          <table>
        <tr>
            # if ((int)CustomerStatus.APPROVED == custStatus && CustomerModel.UserRole == 1) { #
            <td>
                APPROVED
            </td>
            # }
            else {# 
            <td>
            NOT APPROVED
            </td>
            #}
            #

     </tr>
     </table>

</script>
```

Please let me know,how we can check Enum & model inside template...

Comment: I don't think you can cast (int) in javascript??

Comment: @RickS : yes!! you are right , we can't cast int in javascript and as per my understanding we can't use enum & model to check.so what would be the right approach to handle this type of condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing arbitary javascript code in your template (`# expression #`) then you can try to add global variable for your page that contain all your enums value.

Put this script above all your template (in razor page)

```
<script>
var approvedVal = parseInt("@((int)CustomerStatus.APPROVED)");
</script>
```

and your template should be like this

```
<script type="text/kendo-x-tmpl" id="EntitiesTemplate">
    <table>
        <tr>
            # if (custStatus == approvedVal && CustomerModel.UserRole == 1) { #
            <td>APPROVED</td>
            # } else { # 
            <td>NOT APPROVED</td>
            # } #
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```